# Figurative use of words

Tags: idioms, writing, dictionaries, reference, figurative

I love creative writing and especially figurative language. So, very often I dig dictionaries to find the idiomatic uses of words that would potentially 'add spice' in a way I want.
All dictionaries have the feature but it's very limited. However Oxford collocations dictionary is super useful, I guess there must be something more specific.

I'm actually looking for a reference (website, dictionary, etc) that especially includes figurative uses of words/expressions. For example, if my purpose was to **imply** something it, my implication would be the entry and word/expression would be the outcome. Something like a creative reverse dictionary.
For exampl, the following are my own way of thinking, so I need a dictionary to do this, when I'm lost :)

(***imply*** --------------------------> ***return***)

***too much of sth*** ----------------> (look in the area of water/liquid) ***be dripping/soaking with sth***

***not putting much effort*** -------> (something around the idea of 'rope' might do) ***slack off***

***improve/ increase sth*** ---------> (must be about pushing up, in mechanics let's say) ***jack up***

***enjoy*** ---------------------------> (as if absorbing-- a 'sponge' pops up) ***soak up***

Comment: how do you get to your figurative concept, e.g. why rope?

Comment: I don't know if it's explicable, but they conjure up in me pictures. Like, when you lessen your effort, to me it pictures a tight rope that is getting loose. Then, I'll go for synonyms of 'loose'.

Comment: I quick Google search turned up reversedictionary.org. I searched for "too much of something" and some results were "flood," "swamp," and "OD."